# Merging features using Collector for ArcGIS (Field Maps)

Tags: polygon, merge, arcgis-collector

In 'Collector for ArcGis',  is it possible to merge two polygon features (from two different layers) into one feature?

It would be required to decide from which layer the attributes are used.

Comment: Edit the question and tag ArcGIS Collector.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You would need to do this either in AGOL or Desktop.

[Here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android-phone/help/capture.htm) are the docs about collection for the latest version of collector.

Answer (score 0):

If your data was published as 'referenced register data' in a database in ArcGIS Enterprise, could you try make a Trigger to merge when feature insert or edit